# jenkins plugin to validate patches?

Tags: jenkins

I have seen a few open source projects validate patches before commiting.  They would have checks like "does this patch add tests?".  I am having a hard time finding a plugin that would let me test a new git patch and validate that it adds what we require to a patch.

What jenkins plugins will let me validate patches before they go into a build?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to start using [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) code review. This together with the [Gerrit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Plugin) for Jenkins will make it a breeze to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks.  Ill look into using gerrit.